# iOS remotebuild fails with "spawn ideviceinstaller ENOENT"

Tags: ios, visual-studio-cordova

I updated the Visual Studio Tools for Apache Cordova to the newest version (14.0.50925.4). Also I updated the remotebuild on the Mac to version 2.0.1.

Now I am able to build, but I am not able to deploy to an iPhone connected to the Mac. With every deploy, the remotebuild crashes with the error

```
spawn ideviceinstaller ENOENT
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:874:11)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:178:32)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:344:16)
    at doNTCallback2 (node.js:439:9)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:353:17)
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to install ideviceinstaller on the Mac by using "brew install ideviceinstaller" in terminal.

https://github.com/libimobiledevice/ideviceinstaller
http://brewformulas.org/Ideviceinstaller

Comment: After installing ideviceinstaller, I got a similar error `spawn ios_webkit_debug_proxy ENOENT`. This I could heal by executing `brew install ios-webkit-debug-proxy` (with hyphen instead of underline).

Now it is working again. Thanks a lot!